# Wordcloud2 - separate words for counting

Tags: r, tidyverse, word-cloud, unnest, tidytext

am trying to extract the words so that I can create a wordcloud but have some difficulties
this is the code:

```
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\me\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\ToPandas.xlsx")

data2 <-data$articlesDescription


#install.packages("wordcloud2")
#install.packages("tidyverse")
#install.packages("tidytext")

library(wordcloud2)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

data2 <- gsub('[^[:alnum:] ]', '', data2)

data2 <-  data2 %>% 
  ungroup()

data3.df <- as.data.frame(data2)
data3 <- data3.df

data3 <- data3%>%
  anti_join(get_stopwords())%>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE)
```

I have put the hash tags in front of the install packages  so it does not try to reinstall.
up to data2 until I start to ungroup then I get this error:

> Error in UseMethod("ungroup") :    no applicable method for 'ungroup'
> applied to an object of class "character"

then when it tries to move forward I get this:

> Error in `anti_join()`: ! `by` must be supplied when `x` and `y` have
> no common variables. i use by = character()` to perform a cross-join.

I think that my error stems from the first error (ungroup) but I can't figure out how to do it so I can count the words

this is a sample of how the imported xlsx file looks like:
[ToPandas_xlsx Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXDjc.png)

Can anyone point me into the right direction?
thanks :)

**EDIT 1:** adding info from json file (had to remove a row since it was over 3.000 characters beyond the limit):

```
{\"articlesName\":\"Texas threatens to become next flash point on voting rules\",\"articlesShortDescription\":\"Texas appeared on Thursday to become the next flash point on politically charged issues in Corporate America after legislation passed by the state Senate to limit voting access prompted a rebuke from American Airlines.\",\"articlesDescription\":\"[{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022WASHINGTON Texas appeared on Thursday to become the next flash point on politically charged issues in Corporate America after legislation passed by the state Senate to limit voting access prompted a rebuke from American Airlines.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022\\u201cWe are strongly opposed to this bill and others like it,\\u201d Fort Worth, Texas-based American said in a statement.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022The legislation, which is now set to go before the Texas House of Representatives, would eliminate drive-through voting, limit polling site hours and give partisan poll watchers more autonomy.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022Southwest Airlines, also based in Texas, declined to say if it opposed the legislation but said: \\u201cWe believe every voter should have a fair opportunity to let their voice be heard. This right is essential to our nation\\u2019s success.\\u201d\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022The Texas effort drew sharp criticism from voting rights advocates and Democrats in the state, who argue that the legislation would make it more difficult for Texans, particularly those of color, to cast ballots.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022The state already has some of the most stringent voting laws in the country, according to election experts. A state House of Representatives committee on Thursday was holding a hearing on a companion bill that would impose other voting restrictions.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022Texas is one of several states, including Georgia, Florida, Arizona and Iowa, where Republican lawmakers have pursued new voting limits after former President Donald Trump falsely blamed his November loss on widespread voter fraud despite no evidence.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022Republican lawmakers say the law is needed to ensure public confidence in election integrity.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022The comments by American and Southwest came after Atlanta-based Delta Air Lines and Coca-Cola on Wednesday joined a growing number of companies that challenged the state of Georgia\\u2019s new voting restrictions.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022Delta CEO Ed Bastian blasted the law on Wednesday in a reversal from an initial statement last week that sparked a popular backlash.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022But his new stance drew condemnation from Georgia\\u2019s Republican Governor Brian Kemp and many Republicans, including Senator Marco Rubio who questioned why Delta criticized Georgia but not China.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022\\u201cFar too many multinational corporations are too eager to make their voices heard on the woke issues of the day in the United States, but remain stunningly silent, or in Delta\\u2019s case, complicit, in real, ongoing atrocities in countries like China.\\u201d Rubio wrote.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022Delta did not immediately comment on Rubio\\u2019s letter.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022The Georgia House late Wednesday voted to repeal a jet fuel sales tax break that Delta uses but the state Senate did not act on it before the legislative session adjourned.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022Kemp told Fox Business he thought the tax issue was \\u201cmoot\\u201d now that the legislature had adjourned.\\u0022}]\",\"minutesToRead\":3,\"primaryAssetType\":0,\"wordCount\":null,\"urlSupplier\":\"https:\\/\\/www.reuters.com\\/article\\/us-usa-election-texas\\/texas-threatens-to-become-next-flash-point-on-voting-rules-idUSKBN2BO6SI\",\"canonicalSupplier\":\"https:\\/\\/www.reuters.com\\/article\\/us-usa-election-texas-idUSKBN2BO6SI\",\"publishedAt\":{\"date\":\"2021-04-01 21:55:32.000000\",\"timezone_type\":3,\"timezone\":\"UTC\"},\"dateModified\":{\"date\":\"2021-04-02 05:15:53.000000\",\"timezone_type\":3,\"timezone\":\"UTC\"},\"files\":[{\"filesName\":null,\"filesTitle\":null,\"filesDescription\":\"Presidio County election judge Lauren Martinez folds a booth after polls and voting ended for the 2020 U.S. presidential election in Marfa, Texas, U.S., November 3, 2020. REUTERS\\/Adrees Latif\",\"contentType\":\"image\\/jpeg\",\"urlCdn\":\"https:\\/\\/static.reuters.com\\/resources\\/r\\/?m=02\\u0026d=20210402\\u0026t=2\\u0026i=1557110638\\u0026r=LYNXMPEH303NA\"}],\"videos\":[],\"tags\":[{\"name\":\"United States\",\"slug\":\"united-states\"},{\"name\":\"Company News\",\"slug\":\"company-news\"},{\"name\":\"Reuters Top News\",\"slug\":\"reuters-top-news\"},{\"name\":\"Government \\/ Politics\",\"slug\":\"government-politics\"},{\"name\":\"Fundamental Rights \\/ Civil Liberties\",\"slug\":\"fundamental-rights-civil-liberties\"},{\"name\":\"Lawmaking\",\"slug\":\"lawmaking\"},{\"name\":\"Airlines (TRBC level 4)\",\"slug\":\"airlines-trbc-level-4\"},{\"name\":\"Elections \\/ Voting\",\"slug\":\"elections-voting\"},{\"name\":\"Regional Airlines (TRBC level 5)\",\"slug\":\"regional-airlines-trbc-level-5\"},{\"name\":\"Texas\",\"slug\":\"texas\"},{\"name\":\"Georgia (US State)\",\"slug\":\"georgia-us-state\"},{\"name\":\"US House of Representatives\",\"slug\":\"us-house-of-representatives\"}],\"keywords\":[{\"keywordName\":\"United States\",\"keywordSlug\":\"united-states\"},{\"keywordName\":\"US\",\"keywordSlug\":\"us\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Company News\",\"keywordSlug\":\"company-news\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Reuters Top News\",\"keywordSlug\":\"reuters-top-news\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Government \\/ Politics\",\"keywordSlug\":\"government-politics\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Fundamental Rights \\/ Civil Liberties\",\"keywordSlug\":\"fundamental-rights-civil-liberties\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Lawmaking\",\"keywordSlug\":\"lawmaking\"},{\"keywordName\":\"USA\",\"keywordSlug\":\"usa\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Airlines (TRBC level 4)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"airlines-trbc-level-4\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Elections \\/ Voting\",\"keywordSlug\":\"elections-voting\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Regional Airlines (TRBC level 5)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"regional-airlines-trbc-level-5\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Texas\",\"keywordSlug\":\"texas\"},{\"keywordName\":\"ELECTION\",\"keywordSlug\":\"election\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Georgia (US State)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"georgia-us-state\"},{\"keywordName\":\"US House of Representatives\",\"keywordSlug\":\"us-house-of-representatives\"}],\"n2\":[],\"authors\":[{\"authorName\":\"Tracy Rucinski\"},{\"authorName\":\"David Shepardson\"},{\"authorName\":\"Joseph Ax\"}]},{\"articlesName\":\"U.S. Supreme Court permits FCC to loosen media ownership rules\",\"articlesShortDescription\":\"The U.S. Supreme Court on Thursday allowed the Federal Communication Commission to loosen local media ownership restrictions, handing a victory to broadcasters in a ruling that could facilitate industry consolidation as consumers increasingly move online.\",\"articlesDescription\":\"[{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022WASHINGTON (Reuters) -The U.S. Supreme Court on Thursday allowed the Federal Communication Commission to loosen local media ownership restrictions, handing a victory to broadcasters in a ruling that could facilitate industry consolidation as consumers increasingly move online.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022In a 9-0 ruling authored by Justice Brett Kavanaugh, the justices overturned a lower court decision that had blocked the FCC\\u2019s repeal of some media ownership regulations in 2017 for failing to consider the effects on ownership by racial minorities and women. Critics of the industry have said further consolidation could limit media choices for consumers.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022The justices acted in appeals by the FCC, companies including News Corp, Fox Corp and Sinclair Broadcast Group Inc and the National Association of Broadcasters.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022The associations for other broadcast networks\\u2019 local affiliates, including ABC, NBC and CBS, backed the appeals, arguing that consolidation would help ensure the economic survival of local television amid heavy competition from internet companies that provide video content. Broadcast television stations have said they are increasingly losing advertising dollars to digital platforms.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022In 2017, the FCC - then led by Republicans during former President Donald Trump\\u2019s administration - voted to eliminate a ban in place since 1975 on cross-ownership of a newspaper and TV station in a major market. It also voted to make it easier for media companies to buy additional TV stations in the same market, and for companies to buy additional radio stations in some markets.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022The FCC, now equally divided between Democrats and Republicans, is led by acting chairwoman Jessica Rosenworcel, a Democrat, who voted against the 2017 decision. The agency is set to have a Democratic majority once President Joe Biden nominates and the Senate confirms a new commissioner. The FCC could then seek to reverse the 2017 order.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022Rosenworcel did not immediately respond to a request for comment after the ruling.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022Writing for the unanimous court, Kavanaugh said that the FCC reasonably reviewed the ownership rules to find that repealing or modifying them \\u201cwas not likely to harm minority and female ownership.\\u201d\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022Kavanaugh added: \\u201cThe FCC reasoned that the historical justifications for those ownership rules no longer apply in today\\u2019s media market, and that permitting efficient combinations among radio stations, television stations and newspapers would benefit consumers.\\u201d\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022The case highlighted diverging views on the best way to ensure a competitive environment that promotes a broad range of local news and information. Critics of the FCC\\u2019s action have said relaxing ownership rules could jeopardize a wider array of sources at the local level.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022The Philadelphia-based 3rd U.S. Circuit Court of Appeals had thwarted the FCC\\u2019s efforts to revise the rules since 2003 in a series of decisions. The new rules were challenged by a number of community advocacy groups led by the Prometheus Radio Project. The 3rd Circuit in 2019 blocked the new rules.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022Former FCC Commissioner Mike O\\u2019Rielly, a Republican who voted for the 2017 order, said he expects there will be some \\u201cstrategic deals\\u201d to consolidate in which a local newspaper could be acquired, but that \\u201cno massive deals\\u201d are going to happen given the struggling local media sector.\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022Cheryl Leanza, a lawyer for the plaintiffs who challenged the 2017 FCC decision, said that \\u201cthe good news is the Biden FCC, once it gains a working majority, can quickly get to work building a solid record to promote the public interest standard and media ownership diversity.\\u201d\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022Advocacy group Free Press said the Biden FCC and Congress \\u201cmust recognize that hedge-fund and Wall Street-driven consolidation harms local communities, and only decimates what\\u2019s left of competition and diversity. ... The silver lining here is (the court) deferred to the agency\\u2019s judgment and left room for a new commission to get this right.\\u201d\\u0022},{\\u0022type\\u0022:\\u0022paragraph\\u0022,\\u0022content\\u0022:\\u0022David Chavern, CEO of the News Media Alliance group that represents more than 2,000 news organizations, hailed the ruling and said the previous restrictions \\u201chad shackled the newspaper industry for far too long. The repeal of the ban will generate much needed investments and cross-platform synergies that will help sustain local news media.\\u201d\\u0022}]\",\"minutesToRead\":5,\"primaryAssetType\":0,\"wordCount\":null,\"urlSupplier\":\"https:\\/\\/www.reuters.com\\/article\\/us-usa-court-fcc\\/u-s-supreme-court-permits-fcc-to-loosen-media-ownership-rules-idUSKBN2BO5S4\",\"canonicalSupplier\":\"https:\\/\\/www.reuters.com\\/article\\/us-usa-court-fcc-idUSKBN2BO5S4\",\"publishedAt\":{\"date\":\"2021-04-01 14:25:10.000000\",\"timezone_type\":3,\"timezone\":\"UTC\"},\"dateModified\":{\"date\":\"2021-04-01 16:45:47.000000\",\"timezone_type\":3,\"timezone\":\"UTC\"},\"files\":[{\"filesName\":null,\"filesTitle\":null,\"filesDescription\":\"The Supreme Court is seen in Washington, U.S., December 11, 2020. REUTERS\\/Joshua Roberts\\/File Photo\",\"contentType\":\"image\\/jpeg\",\"urlCdn\":\"https:\\/\\/static.reuters.com\\/resources\\/r\\/?m=02\\u0026d=20210401\\u0026t=2\\u0026i=1557040208\\u0026r=LYNXMPEH3030U\"}],\"videos\":[],\"tags\":[{\"name\":\"United States\",\"slug\":\"united-states\"},{\"name\":\"Corporate Events\",\"slug\":\"corporate-events\"},{\"name\":\"Company News\",\"slug\":\"company-news\"},{\"name\":\"Financials (Legacy)\",\"slug\":\"financials-legacy\"},{\"name\":\"Financials (TRBC level 1)\",\"slug\":\"financials-trbc-level-1\"},{\"name\":\"Arts \\/ Culture \\/ Entertainment\",\"slug\":\"arts-culture-entertainment\"},{\"name\":\"Reuters Top News\",\"slug\":\"reuters-top-news\"},{\"name\":\"Major News\",\"slug\":\"major-news\"},{\"name\":\"Cyclical Consumer Services (TRBC level 2)\",\"slug\":\"cyclical-consumer-services-trbc-level-2\"},{\"name\":\"Consumer Cyclicals (TRBC level 1)\",\"slug\":\"consumer-cyclicals-trbc-level-1\"},{\"name\":\"Technology (TRBC level 1)\",\"slug\":\"technology-trbc-level-1\"},{\"name\":\"Technology \\/ Media \\/ Telecoms\",\"slug\":\"technology-media-telecoms\"},{\"name\":\"General News\",\"slug\":\"general-news\"},{\"name\":\"Government \\/ Politics\",\"slug\":\"government-politics\"},{\"name\":\"Media \\u0026 Publishing (TRBC level 3)\",\"slug\":\"media-publishing-trbc-level-3\"},{\"name\":\"Media \\/ Publishing (Legacy)\",\"slug\":\"media-publishing-legacy\"},{\"name\":\"Society \\/ Social Issues\",\"slug\":\"society-social-issues\"},{\"name\":\"Crime \\/ Law \\/ Justice\",\"slug\":\"crime-law-justice\"},{\"name\":\"Corporate \\/ Market Regulation\",\"slug\":\"corporate-market-regulation\"},{\"name\":\"Judicial Process \\/ Court Cases \\/ Court Decisions\",\"slug\":\"judicial-process-court-cases-court-decisions\"},{\"name\":\"Broadcasting (TRBC level 4)\",\"slug\":\"broadcasting-trbc-level-4\"},{\"name\":\"US Government News\",\"slug\":\"us-government-news\"},{\"name\":\"Consumer Publishing (TRBC level 4)\",\"slug\":\"consumer-publishing-trbc-level-4\"},{\"name\":\"Broadcasting (NEC) (TRBC level 5)\",\"slug\":\"broadcasting-nec-trbc-level-5\"},{\"name\":\"Advertising \\u0026 Marketing (TRBC level 4)\",\"slug\":\"advertising-marketing-trbc-level-4\"},{\"name\":\"Women\\u0027s Issues\",\"slug\":\"womens-issues\"},{\"name\":\"Race Relations \\/ Ethnic Issues\",\"slug\":\"race-relations-ethnic-issues\"},{\"name\":\"Newspaper Publishing (TRBC level 5)\",\"slug\":\"newspaper-publishing-trbc-level-5\"},{\"name\":\"Television Broadcasting (TRBC level 5)\",\"slug\":\"television-broadcasting-trbc-level-5\"},{\"name\":\"US Supreme Court\",\"slug\":\"us-supreme-court\"}],\"keywords\":[{\"keywordName\":\"United States\",\"keywordSlug\":\"united-states\"},{\"keywordName\":\"US\",\"keywordSlug\":\"us\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Corporate Events\",\"keywordSlug\":\"corporate-events\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Company News\",\"keywordSlug\":\"company-news\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Financials (Legacy)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"financials-legacy\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Financials (TRBC level 1)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"financials-trbc-level-1\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Arts \\/ Culture \\/ Entertainment\",\"keywordSlug\":\"arts-culture-entertainment\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Reuters Top News\",\"keywordSlug\":\"reuters-top-news\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Major News\",\"keywordSlug\":\"major-news\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Cyclical Consumer Services (TRBC level 2)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"cyclical-consumer-services-trbc-level-2\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Consumer Cyclicals (TRBC level 1)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"consumer-cyclicals-trbc-level-1\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Technology (TRBC level 1)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"technology-trbc-level-1\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Technology \\/ Media \\/ Telecoms\",\"keywordSlug\":\"technology-media-telecoms\"},{\"keywordName\":\"General News\",\"keywordSlug\":\"general-news\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Government \\/ Politics\",\"keywordSlug\":\"government-politics\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Media \\u0026 Publishing (TRBC level 3)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"media-publishing-trbc-level-3\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Media \\/ Publishing (Legacy)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"media-publishing-legacy\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Society \\/ Social Issues\",\"keywordSlug\":\"society-social-issues\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Crime \\/ Law \\/ Justice\",\"keywordSlug\":\"crime-law-justice\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Corporate \\/ Market Regulation\",\"keywordSlug\":\"corporate-market-regulation\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Judicial Process \\/ Court Cases \\/ Court Decisions\",\"keywordSlug\":\"judicial-process-court-cases-court-decisions\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Broadcasting (TRBC level 4)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"broadcasting-trbc-level-4\"},{\"keywordName\":\"USA\",\"keywordSlug\":\"usa\"},{\"keywordName\":\"COURT\",\"keywordSlug\":\"court\"},{\"keywordName\":\"US Government News\",\"keywordSlug\":\"us-government-news\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Consumer Publishing (TRBC level 4)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"consumer-publishing-trbc-level-4\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Broadcasting (NEC) (TRBC level 5)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"broadcasting-nec-trbc-level-5\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Advertising \\u0026 Marketing (TRBC level 4)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"advertising-marketing-trbc-level-4\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Women\\u0027s Issues\",\"keywordSlug\":\"womens-issues\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Race Relations \\/ Ethnic Issues\",\"keywordSlug\":\"race-relations-ethnic-issues\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Newspaper Publishing (TRBC level 5)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"newspaper-publishing-trbc-level-5\"},{\"keywordName\":\"Television Broadcasting (TRBC level 5)\",\"keywordSlug\":\"television-broadcasting-trbc-level-5\"},{\"keywordName\":\"US Supreme Court\",\"keywordSlug\":\"us-supreme-court\"},{\"keywordName\":\"FCC\",\"keywordSlug\":\"fcc\"}],\"n2\":[],\"authors\":[{\"authorName\":\"Andrew Chung\"},{\"authorName\":\"David Shepardson\"}]}
```

Comment: You need to share your data so the example is completely reproducible. Do this `dput(head(data))` and paste the result of this command into the original question.

Comment: tried. file is too big. would attaching a link to it do?

Comment: The key to getting a resolution is to post the minimum code and data to allow someone else to recreate the problem. Does `dput(head(data))` provide enough to allow this to happen?

Comment: @dcarlson , will try your suggestion and let you know

Comment: @AndrewChisholm, added what I could from json file. went over the limit. had to remove a row

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be enough to get you started:

```
test <- data.frame(Text = rep("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.", 5))
```

Now split out the words:

```
test.lst <- strsplit(test$Text, " ")
test.lst[[1]]
#  [1] "The"    "quick"  "brown"  "fox"    "jumped" "over"   "the"    "lazy"   "dog's"  "back."
```

Get rid of the punctuation:

```
test.lst2 <- lapply(test.lst, function(x) gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x))
test.lst2[[1]]
#  [1] "The"    "quick"  "brown"  "fox"    "jumped" "over"   "the"    "lazy"   "dogs"   "back"
```

`test.lst2` is a list containing a part for each row of the data. If you want to collapse. To get frequencies:

table(unlist(test.lst2))

```
  back  brown   dogs    fox jumped   lazy   over  quick    the    The 
     5      5      5      5      5      5      5      5      5      5
```

Comment: thanks, have separated the words. am trying to get the word lcoud2 via df or tibble but have had no luck so far. 
if I try:
> df <- df %>%
+   anti_join(get_stopwords())%>%
+   unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
+   count(words, sort = TRUE)
I get : Error in count(., words, sort = TRUE) : unused argument (sort = TRUE)

if I try:
> df <- df %>%
+   anti_join(get_stopwords())%>%
+   unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
+   dplyr::count(words, sort = TRUE)
Error in `anti_join()`:
! `by` must be supplied when `x` and `y` have no common variables.
i use by = character()` to perform a cross-join.